# Separate Launcher and Activity icon with Android

Tags: android, android-activity, icons, launcher

I've got a simple application with one single activity. Actually, the launcher icon is the same as the activity's one (the one in the top-left corner). I would like to put another icon in my activity without changing the launchers'one.

Here is my manifest :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.natinusala.pebkac.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter android:logo="@drawable/pebkac">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Actually, I can edit the launcher and activity icon by editing the `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` line. I can do it also in adding an `android:icon` into the `<activity>` but it modify too the launcher's icon.

How can I do to edit my activity's icon without touching the launcher's one ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your manifest, add `android:logo="@drawable/ic_yourIcon"` to either your Activity or Application tag.

Comment: @natinusala If it works why not accepting the answer?

Comment: @natinusala Thanks for him. I'm looking for users asking well defined questions and rewarding correctly. You are such  a candidate.